# How to convert pandas dataframe to 3D Panel

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading data from a CSV file which contains weather data for a network of buoys situated off the coast of Ireland. it is a time series dataset with hourly readings for each buoy. I want to create a 3D structure where there is a dataframe for each buoy, containing the columns of the weather conditions, indexed by the date and time.

I would like to be able to access the data via the following syntax:

```
df['column']['anotherColumn']
```

I'm aware that pandas has a deprecated Panel class, but I can't work out how to do this otherwise.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Use a multi level index?

Comment: I'll look into it. I'm new to pandas so yet to work out the finer details, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The pandas `Panel` was deprecated in favour of `DataFrame` with multi-level index. To quote from the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/advanced.html#hierarchical-indexing-multiindex):

> Hierarchical / Multi-level indexing is very exciting as it opens the
>   door to some quite sophisticated data analysis and manipulation,
>   especially for working with higher dimensional data. In essence, it
>   enables you to store and manipulate data with an arbitrary number of
>   dimensions in lower dimensional data structures like Series (1d) and
>   DataFrame (2d).

Here's a quick example of a DataFrame with MultiIndex used to represent a three-dimensional data set:

```
In [1]: multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([
   ...:     ['buoy1', 'buoy1', 'buoy2', 'buoy2', 'buoy3', 'buoy3', 'buoy4', 'buoy4'],
   ...:     ['wind', 'water', 'wind', 'water', 'wind', 'water', 'wind', 'water'],
   ...: ])

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 8), columns=multi_index)

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
      buoy1               buoy2               buoy3               buoy4
       wind     water      wind     water      wind     water      wind     water
0  1.082442 -0.148975 -0.372837  0.075599  1.681150  0.910194  0.157064  0.183764
1 -0.019759  1.782505 -1.092751  0.324313 -2.217671  0.349224  1.085250 -0.715607
2 -1.308382 -0.994506 -0.306874  0.517858  1.356037 -0.024291  0.085105 -0.073061
```

Subsequently you can slice down to a 2D section of your data set like so:

```
In [4]: df['buoy3']
Out[4]:
       wind     water
0  1.681150  0.910194
1 -2.217671  0.349224
2  1.356037 -0.024291
```

And you can slice down to a 1D section (i.e. single column) of your data set like so:

```
In [5]: df['buoy3']['water']
Out[5]:
0    0.910194
1    0.349224
2   -0.024291
Name: water, dtype: float64
```